# how to set up multiple speakers?

Tags: audio, speakers, volume-mixer

I have a pair of active studio speakers and I am looking to add a subwoofer and later 2 more speakers for. I am looking for simpler ways to connect/control the speakers to a computer.

The  way I imagine it is: I need something that connects to a computer through USB, is pretty much like a mixer but with multiple channel outputs, rather than inputs.

Comment: check out the *big knob by mackie* (which is actually a safe search in google)

Comment: What kind of audio device do you have installed? generally, you would want to buy the speakers you need to work as a set, so if you need 5.1, you order a box with 6 speakers. that said, if your speakers have 3.5mm plugs, and your PC has a sound card capable of addressing the number of channels you need, you can assign plugs on your sound card to the additional channels. if you don't have a multi-channel sound device installed, you will probably have to purchase one.